# Allow users to create their own Stack Overflow sites, like Google groups

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Currently there is no good resource for quality mailing lists on the net, with Google groups being the best, but still kludgy.

Suggestion: Allow users to create their *own* yyy.stackoverflow.com, which uses Stack Overflow semantics.  It has potential to become quite popular.

Comment: Can someone elaborate on what this is for those of us not familiar with Google Groups?

Comment: @Weblog, Google groups is a web-interface (google, incidentally..) for the very old Usenet newsgroups (which is still very much alive).

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: didn't you mean "status-declined"?

Comment: @Peter - no, I mean completed. Area51 effectively accomplishes this.

Comment: @Joel actually I was more suggesting one that would be open to any new groups, arbitrarily...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that would create way too much fragmentation. The [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) initiative takes care of this by letting the sites with the most demand emerge.

I mean, just like with news groups, you'd get a lot of sites that are quite alike. I'd rather have just one StackOverflow instead of 10.

Comment: True, and stackoverflow itself handles this with tags, which is...I suppose good enough for now.  That doesn't mean there isn't a niche for something better than google groups but I suppose stack overflow isn't it.