# How do I create a "Stack" site like www.paleohacks.com?

Tags: support, api

I am trying to get my developers to create a "Stack" question-and-answer site like `paleohacks.com`, and I have a key, but I have no idea what to do next. Help!

Comment: Questions about the API belong on [StackApps](http://stackapps.com). Thanks.

Comment: @sean, what do you mean, "I have a key"?

Comment: Surprisingly, I couldn't find a dupe of this, but here are two related questions: [one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5558/am-i-allowed-to-make-a-stackoverflow-clone) and [two](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59927/allow-users-to-create-their-own-stack-overflow-sites-like-google-groups)

Comment: @Jon I don't think this is an API question, the OP wants to create his own SO clone. Which strikes me as an SO question, actually... why was this migrated, anyone know?

Comment: @Pop: Honestly I'm not sure the approach being taken here. The post says "I have a key" which, unless it's a total typo, I interpret to mean "I have an API key." Of course, that's not the correct approach to solve the problem...

Comment: @Jon, fair enough. I've spent enough time on this unanswerably vague question, voting to close.

Comment: @Pop, isn't this on topic for StackOverflow, since it's a question about software development, in which case it should be migrated back to where it's on topic?

Comment: @dsolimano, yes, it would be on-topic for SO, but a reverse migration would have to be done manually, and this question is so poorly written that I don't see that happening.

Answer (score 2):

Paleohacks seems to be a StackExchange 1.0 site, which is no longer available.  You could try to get a proposal through the [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) process, or possibly use one of the open source StackExchange clones floating around the web.  Some are [listed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4381/open-source-knock-offs).

EDIT:

Here's a [more complete list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) of clones.

Comment: And to add to this, existing Stack Exchange 1.0 sites have only a few months before they must either upgrade to 2.0 or find other hosting.  See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/